# SQL- how to join 3 tables but only group by columns from two

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, max

I am trying to join 3 tables below together but I only want to group by `customer_ID` In the first 2 table, how to achieve this?
In other words the third table I use is only to eliminate the records. Many thanks!

table 1

```
customer_ID  product_No  
 100          ABC001
 100          ABC111
 100          ABC112 
 200          ABC002
```

table2

```
product_No   Amount
 ABC001        10
 ABC002        50
 ABC111        60
 ABC112        70
```

table 3

```
Valid_Product  Desc
 ABC001         Y
 ABC111         Y
```

I'm ok with joining table 1 and 2 by doing

```
select 
    t1.product_No, Max(t2.amount)
from 
    t1, t2
where 
    t1.product_No = t2.product_No
group by 
    customer_ID
```

Now how do I in the same query join to table 3 and only get the value of ABC111 for customer 100 as that's the valid product with Max amount?

so the result would be `Customer_ID  100  Amount 60` The goal is to get the max amount of a product (only if the product is in the 3rd table with a desc Y) under a customer.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve.  Saying you want to `group by` and `join` doesn't help . . . because that is not exactly what you want to do.  Your attempt at a query in the question is simply invalid.

Comment: What is the role of table 3 in your desired output?can you be more specific please?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to get the max amount of a product (only if the product is in the 3rd table) under a customer , that’s why I used group by. Does it make more sense? Thanks.

Comment: @codeLover I edited the question with a goal at the end to explain. Does it make more sense? Thanks

Comment: It's still not clear: your desired output has CUSTOMER_ID in the projection by your current query has PRODUCT_ID. Which is correct?

Comment: @user4046073 . . . See my answer.  It appears to be what you want.

Comment: On a sidenote: You should always explain your tables. Either showing the create statement or at least by telling us their unique keys. Can a product occur multiple times in t1? Even for the same customer? Can a product appear multiple times in t2? Can a product appear multiple times in t3? Even with the same desc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just another join and a WHERE clause filtering on `t3.desc`. It doesn't seem like you need the columns from `T3` in the projection.

```
select t1.customer_ID, Max(t2.amount)
from t1
     join t2
     on t1.product_No = t2.product_No
     join t3
     on t1.product_No = t3.valid_product
where t3.desc = 'Y'
Group by t1.customer_ID
```

---

Incidentally, you will notice I wrote the query using the ANSI 92 join syntax. Oracle has supported this since 9i (twenty years now) and it really does make queries easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to explain more about the goal and the purpose of Y in table 3

Answer (score 1):

If for each customer you want the valid product with the maximum amount, then use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (select t1.*, t2.amount,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.customer_id t2.amount desc) as seqnum
      from t1 join
           t2
           on t1.product_No = t2.product_No join
           t3
           on t3.Valid_Product = t1.product_No
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your output sample simple aggregate function and join is enough

```
select t1.*,t2.Amount from table1 t1 join

 (
 select * from table2 t2 where amount in
   ( 
    select max(Amount) as amt
   from table2 inner join table3 t3 on 
    t2.product_No=t3.Valid_Product

   )  
  ) t2 on t1.product_No=t2.product_No
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to know whether a product exists in table 3. We check existence in SQL with `EXISTS` or `IN`.

```
select 
  t1.customer_id, max(t2.amount)
from t2
left join t2 on  t2.product_no = t1.product_no
where t1.product_no in (select product_no from t3 where desc = 'Y')
group by t1.customer_id
order by t1.customer_id;
```

Don't join, when you are only looking up a table whether an entry exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try below using row_number()

```
select * from 
(select customer_ID,t1.product_No, t2.amount, row_number() over (partition by customerid order by amount desc) as rn
from t1 inner join t2
where t1.product_No = t2.product_No)a
inner join table3 on a.product_no = Valid_Product
where rn=1
```